# Are these figures accurate or is it a bug in the views-counting feature?

Tags: discussion

I saw that [a question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/ways-of-saying-youre-welcome-in-french) has a ridiculous number of views (224k), compared to all others. Did some web bot somewhat manage to automatically request this page for technical reasons unrelated to the question itself and make the counter skyrocket ? Or is the number of views actually accurate, reflecting that many people are genuinely interested in it ?

(I tagged *bug* but for this case it meant more precisely *bug?*)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16366115#16366115

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the top referring terms from search engines (from mod-only analytics):

[image]

Seems like people just *really* want to be polite in French. N.B. those 'visits' numbers are sampled, and the real figure is likely much higher.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I must admit I'm quite baffled...

Comment: @RomainVALERI Sometimes we just get lucky and have certain questions that just tickle the internet's fancy :)